# Частота вызова OnInspectorGUI ()

Tags: unity3d

Какая частота вызова у OnInspectorGUI?

Comment: Впиши туда, `Debag.Log("OnInspectorGUI");`... может быть узнаешь.

Comment: он разве не будет просто выводить текст?